# Apache not serving anything for errors

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, httpd.conf

I have Apache set up through XAMPP on a Windows 7 x64 system, and for some reason it isn't serving any error pages. I have

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

set up in both httpd.conf and .htaccess in my webroot dir, but whenever I purposefully request a page that doesn't exist to test it, Apache returns nothing at all - not my 404 error page or the default Apache 404 page, just a blank page, with nothing in it at all. I think this is one of the "soft 404" problems, because the Apache logs and Chrome both say that the request for the non-existent page resulted in a 200 OK response, but I have no idea how to fix it, because I'm not getting anything from the server. The logs don't tell me anything, and my searches on Google / etc. haven't resulted in any solutions for the problem I'm facing. Could it be that because I'm using a PHP semi-redirect script to route all requests that would have gone to `http://localhost/*` to `http://localhost/testing/` that errors are being generated and then interpreted as not errors? For example, a request for `http://localhost/foo.html` will redirect to `http://localhost/testing/` (not /testing/foo.html, but this is expected behavior), but a request for `http://locahost/testing/foo.html` (which doesn't exist) will result in a empty page and a 200 OK from Apache. If I request a page that exists though I usually get what I want, but sometimes Apache will also send back nothing at all for a PHP script that exists - for example I'm playing with sNews, and a request for index.php (`http://localhost/testing/snews/index.php`) will result in a blank page, even when the page has HTML that should display even if nothing is parsed / inserted.

Other then this, PHP, MySQL, Perl, and almost everything else works perfectly. A normal page will load if it exists, and the only problems that exist are those explained above, and this is really annoying because it's preventing me from finishing a certain project. Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `http://localhost/404.html` work?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's a static page so Apache serves it properly, as far as I know at least.

Comment: Actually, the page is located at http://localhost/testing/404.html - even when the .htaccess reads ErrorDocument 404 /testing/404.html it gives me nothing.

Comment: Next question would be are you sure your .htaccess if being read and applied?

Comment: Yes, Basic Redirect Rules work, as do things such as Options +Indexes even though I've turned those off in httpd.conf.

Comment: Now after some Tinkering I seem to have fixed it, it seems like the combination of .htaccess and PHP-based redirecting was breaking Apache's  error sending. The errors in /testing/ were for some reason being acted upon by the PHP in the web root, ( / ) and thus resulting in a return 0 with nothing in the returned page. 

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this question despite how long it's been since it was relevant:

Problem was Apache and PHP had conflicting directives - PHP would route all requests for `/` to `/testing` and Apache would look for error pages in `/` but get redirected by PHP and therefore fail.